# Altering only the time of a date timestamp of BIGINT type

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'd like to set the time as 00:00:00 in stock_date without altering the year, month or date i.e. if the date representation is `07-07-1994 10:45:23`, I'd like to alter it as `07-07-1994 00:00:00` I've looked around but didn't find anything that might help. Following is my query. Thanks.

```
SELECT stock_date          AS longDate,
       'Tagged containers' AS transactionType,
       tagged_cnt          AS quantity
FROM RFID_INVENTORY_DAILY_STOCK
WHERE grp_org_id = (SELECT GRP_ORG_ID
                    FROM GROUP_ORG_MAPPING
                    WHERE
                    grp_id =#group_id#
                    AND org_type = 'S' AND isactive=1
                    LIMIT 1) 
  AND stock_date >= #fromDate# 
  AND stock_date <= #toDate#
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `date_trunc` like this:

```
SELECT date_trunc('day', current_timestamp);

       date_trunc       
------------------------
 2017-10-06 00:00:00+02
(1 row)
```